# .htaccess/mod_rewrite: running Angular app in sub-folder?

Tags: php, angular, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've

1. a light `index.php` which provides simple pages and
2. a more complex/heavy Angular 8.0 app, stored in the sub-folder `/app`.

**Example URLs:**

```
/ ......................... works: index.php, loads home page
/my-blog-post.html ........ works: index.php, loads a blog post
/any-page.htm ............. works: index.php, loads a page
/app ...................... works: home page of the Angular app
/app/login ................ DOES "NOT" WORK: sub-page of the Angular app
```

**Folder structure:**

```
app/dist/app ........................................... Angular App (built files)
app/dist/app/3rdpartylicenses.txt
app/dist/app/4-es5.86e9c53554535b1b46a8.js
app/dist/app/4-es2015.bb174fcd0205a5f23647.js
app/dist/app/5-es5.b8f3fede0599cda91cf0.js
app/dist/app/5-es2015.f4890df5957b350d78ca.js
app/dist/app/favicon.ico
app/dist/app/index.html
app/dist/app/main-es5.8059496aa1855103a2ad.js
app/dist/app/main-es2015.0629f594e2c4c056133c.js
app/dist/app/polyfills-es5.943113ac054b16d954ae.js
app/dist/app/polyfills-es2015.e954256595c973372414.js
app/dist/app/runtime-es5.f2faa6ae2b23db85cc8d.js
app/dist/app/runtime-es2015.f40f45bfff52b2130730.js
app/dist/app/styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css
.htaccess .............................................. 
index.php ..............................................
```

**app/dist/app/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App</title>
  <base href="/app/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.f40f45bfff52b2130730.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.e954256595c973372414.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.f2faa6ae2b23db85cc8d.js" nomodule></script><script src="polyfills-es5.943113ac054b16d954ae.js" nomodule></script><script src="main-es2015.0629f594e2c4c056133c.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.8059496aa1855103a2ad.js" nomodule></script></body>
</html>
```

**Problem:**
It's possible to reach `/app` and afterwards `app/login` by clicking a link within the Angular App. It is **not possible** to reach the URL **directly** via the browsers address bar:

1. `app/login` does not work when called directly (error below)
2. `app/` -> click *Login-link* -> `app/login` works

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Page
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /index.php?module=page&slug=$1

# Blog
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$ /index.php?module=blog&slug=$1

# Angular app
RewriteRule ^app/$ app/dist/app/index.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/(.*) app/dist/app/$1 [L]

# Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

**Error**

```
# /var/log/apache2/myproject_error.log
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I think the bug is somewhere in the routing of Angular app part of the `.htaccess`.
 `index.php` and the Angular app themselves work perfectly fine.

**Edit**
After setting `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})]` it works with `#`, but I'd like to avoid the `HashLocationStrategy`.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# remove www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Page
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.html$ index.php?module=page&slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Blog
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.htm$ index.php?module=blog&slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Angular app
RewriteRule ^app/$ app/dist/app/index.html [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/(.+)$ app/dist/app/$1 [L,NC]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache or test in a new browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's unfortunately the same problem: when I call `/app` directly via the browser and then click on the login-link it works, but not if I enter `/app/login` directly. (Tested in cleared Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Do you have other htacceas in your system or other rules not shown here?

Comment: ok try my updated code. Make sure you have only this code while testing. Also can you show content of `app/dist/app/` directory by editing your question.

Comment: I updated the `.htaccess`, still the same problem. The browser shows `The requested URL /app/dist/app/login was not found on this server.`, but it still works with clicking *Login*. I edited my qustion and added the folder content and content of `index.html`.

Comment: But now you're getting a different error i.e. `not found` instead of  `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects` right?

Comment: I got the same error before on the browser, but the error in the log is gone. One error less! :-) I just installed another browser to be 100% sure that the cache was cleared, same result.

Comment: I just put the Angular app in another directory, without an `.htaccess` file and it's the same problem. It looks like the Angular routing doesn't work properly in the built version. It still works if I call the index page and then navigate. Just the direct call is not working.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no understanding of Angular routing to find a way out. I suspect when you navigate on index.php then it works by loading page component by adding `#something` at the end of URL

Comment: I ended up with using `#`, but your answer was the closest. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your HTTP server to redirect all URI which began with **www.domain.com/app/** to the index.html(angular app) file so that it always serve index.html on **app/**.

Here's how angular suggests: [Angular Deployment Server Configuration](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was describing a particular problem which is the behavior of calling the URL directly or navigating through the Android app.